# Blender 2.7 Select vertex path option

Tags: vertices, selection-tools

I am following the "Blender Inside Out" tutorial on blender cloud. Chapter 4 UV Wrapping - Learn the basics about UV Wrapping and how to set seams, shows how to select a vertex path between a start and end vertex. The video says pressing <kbd>W</kbd> should bring up a menu, which shows the option to Select vertex path. The tutorial uses blender 2.6, I have installed 2.7. I do not see this option in 2.7. Does anyone know how to access this option on 2.7?

Required path:
[image]

Select shortest path result:

[image]

Comment: Press Space, and search for it.

Comment: @someonewithpc, did that, did not find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's right there for me in 2.72:

[image]

For the squigglyness, try changing the *length* option in the redo panel (<kbd>F6</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: @sotn, you can also use Ctrl RMB to use this feature.

Comment: @user2859 Wow, I didn't know that.. Thanks! That is insanely useful :D

Comment: @user2859, I can use that option, but I am wondering why the option shown in the tutorial is not available in 2.7.

Comment: @sotn Is it still not there for you? Could you upload a screenshot?

Comment: @gandalf3, I added a couple of images. Using select shortest path results in a squiggly path. The required path shown in the tutorial is a straight path from the forehead to the nape. In the tutorial 'Select vetext path' creates this straight line and not a squiggly line.

Comment: @gandalf3, thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: I wasn't aware of F6 bringing up the redo panel (I didn't know the name of it either), so I upvoted for that :-)